# React-router not matching on valid route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I cannot get this react router to match on second part of a path no matter what I do.

Express server is returning index.html for any URL match (I'm not getting a GET error on any URL so I assume this is fine)

```
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});
```

Here are some examples of routes i've tried, which should be valid rules  according to react router [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteMatching.md#path-syntax)

**Example 1 )**

```
<Route path="test">
  <IndexRoute component={Home} />
  <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
</Route>
```

OR

```
<Route path="test">
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
</Route>
```

**`http://localhost:3100/test` = Success > Returns home component
`http://localhost:3100/test/login`  = Fail > gives me blank screen**

**Example 2 )**

```
 <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
```

**`http://localhost:3100/login` = Success > Returns login component**

**Example 3 )**

```
 <Route path="/test/login" component={Login} />
```

OR

```
 <Route path="test/login" component={Login} />
```

**`http://localhost:3100/test/login` = Fail > gives me blank screen**

I'm using version 2.5, Any help would be much appreciated!

** Yarn dump of react router **

```
react-router@^2.5.0:
  version "2.8.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react-router/-/react-router-2.8.1.tgz#73e9491f6ceb316d0f779829081863e378ee4ed7"
  dependencies:
    history "^2.1.2"
    hoist-non-react-statics "^1.2.0"
    invariant "^2.2.1"
    loose-envify "^1.2.0"
    warning "^3.0.0"
```

Comment: did you try `<Route path="/login" component={Home} />`?

Comment: Have you tried removing the slash from "/login"? I think in that way you specify absolute path, so the `http://localhost:3100/login` should work for 1st example?

Comment: for your second example change it to 
<Route path="/login" component={Login} />

Comment: @DamienLeroux I require 2 paths to work, Test is just an example, It could be just login but I need /example/login to work. Mazzu and pavel i've tried both of them, They work with 1 path but not 2 :/

Comment: Updated my examples

Comment: Are you sure your Login component code is loading? if you console.log() or alert() in it, outside the component definition, does that fire? When you try to go to that URL, in the js log, is it complaining that the url doesn't match any route?

Answer (score 0):

Try `path="login"` instead of `path="/login"` . The slash before path is not needed in nested routes.

```
<Route path="test/">
  <IndexRoute component={Home} />
  <Route path="login" component={Login} />
</Route>
```

Comment: I've tried all combinations of slashes, Nothing works whether I include or exclude the slash before the login. If I use this http://localhost:3100/test does not load home, and http://localhost:3100/test/login also does not work. In the original code  http://localhost:3100/test does load home, but the second path does not work

Answer (score 0):

From [express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html), `app.get('/*'` uses regular expression. so, `'/*'` work for 0 to n '/'. Try:

```
app.get('/.*
```

`/.*` should resolve '/' + 0 to n caractères.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies more with the way you are rendering your app than react-router itself, since you are not getting a route not found message but a blank screen, I suggest the following.

when you create your history object do the following

```
import { useRouterHistory } from 'react-router';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';

// ========================================================
// Browser History Setup
// ========================================================
const createHistory = (basename) => {
  return useRouterHistory(createBrowserHistory)({
    basename: basename
  })
}

const history = createHistory('/test');
```

Your route configuration will then look like this

```
<Route path="/" component={App} >
  <IndexRoute component={Home} />
  <Route path="login" component={Login} />
</Route>
```

Your App component would then look something like this

```
export const App extends Component = {
 render() {
   return(
    <div class='app-container'>
     {this.props.children}
    </div>
   )
 }
}

App.propTypes = {
 children: PropTypes.element.isRequired
}

export default App;
```

You'll then be able to access and render the component Login @ `/test/login`